# R merge on unequal column values

Tags: r, merge

This seems to be a simple question, but I cannot get this to work. How do I make a merge in R using a condition where two column values would have to be unequal?

So, for example with the following data.frame:

```
column1 <- c('a','b','c', 'a', 'a', 'a')
column2 <- c('1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3')
df <- data.frame(column1, column2)
```

I could merge the data.frame with itself by doing:

```
result <- merge(x=df, y=df, by.x="column1", by.y="column1")
```

But, what if I would only want that merge to work when the column1 values would be equal but column2 values unequal?

In SQL that would work like this:

```
SELECT 
  L.column1
  L.column2 AS column2_left
  R.column2 AS column2_right
FROM DF L

LEFT JOIN DF R
  ON L.column1 = R.column1
  AND L.column2 != R.column2
```

But how can I do this in R?

So, I would like to have the following result:

```
column1 <- c('a', 'a')
column2.left <- c('1', '1')
column2.right <- c('2', '3')
df <- data.frame(column1, column2.left, column2.right)
```

Comment: The result of the SQL statement shown is not the same as the `df` shown at the end of the question.  What is it that you want?

Comment: Why not merge and then do a filter step? In the background of the SQL query it does a full outer join, then applies filters. Just recreate the behavior in R.

Comment: Yes, I think the join and the filter is then the best approach, I thought there might be an easier way, but this will work too!